# ssh-copy-id ask for password

Tags: ssh, users

I created user and generated key with this commands

```
root# mkdir /usr/share/foreman/.ssh
root# chmod 700 /usr/share/foreman/.ssh
root# chown user:user/usr/share/foreman/.ssh

root# su user -s /bin/bash
user$ ssh-keygen
```

And then tryed to copy key (on same server) between user and root

```
user$ ssh-copy-id root@hostname.com
user$ ssh root@hostname.com
```

But when tryint to `ssh-copy-id` root is asking for password. Don't know why.

Found on internet commenting UsePAM can fix the issue, but did not worked for me.

```
#UsePAM yes
```

I have also in my sshd_config this option allowed

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
ssh-copy-id root@hostname.com
```

works by SSHing into the server and copying your SSH public key(s) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If you don't already have public-key authentication, you will be asked for a password when SSHing into the server during this.

Comment: Problem is when I use password it wont accept it, even it's really proper one.

Comment: You're trying to log into root with a password, by default this isn't allowed. On the server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, what is `PermitRootLogin` set to?

Comment: there is commented `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`

Comment: The default value is `prohibit-password`. This means that SSHing into a server as root is allowed, but password authentication is explicitly not allowed. Either you can change this to `no` (**NOT recommended**), or you can manually copy the public key part of your key (ending in `.pub`) into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Interesting is that, I tryed to login from differend machine and use `ssh-copy-id` and it worked. It's seems like not working only for that specific user.

Comment: If the user you were logging into wasn't root, then password authentication would be allowed with your current configuration (after setting up pubkey auth, you may want to disable this). Logging into root would also be allowed if you were using pubkey or any other auth method that isn't password.

Comment: @Delirium *on the same server* you could simply (as root) append the newly created `id_rsa.pub` file to root's `.ssh/authorized_keys` (using `cat` or `tee` for example)